# HorizontalPodAutoscaler | Set/Update Variable Value

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, horizontal-scaling

Is there a way to use `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` and achieve scaling up/down and along with that update a value (either Helm Variable like `.Values.foo` or an environemnt variable inside the running pod)?

**Backround**:
I am looking for a Open Source Postgres installation that has the ability to Scale. I found a good once here https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql-ha

This package has documentated manual way to scale, with a command like `helm install/upgrade test . --set postgresql.replicaCount=1`

I am trying to put a `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` to this package.

Also read: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/2931

---

**Summary of Research**:

- There is a environment variable called `REPMGR_PARTNER_NODES`
- This maintains a list of known replicas in format `APP_NAME-postgresql-ha-postgresql-REPLICA_NUM.APP_NAME-postgresql-ha-postgresql-headless.default.svc.cluster.local`
- This is populated by `templates/postgresql/statefulset.yaml` in its env section
- The replication is to be set on the StatefulSet
- The statefulset auto create PVC
- We can check replicate via `kubectl describe statefulset test-postgresql-ha-postgresql | grep Replicas:`

---

**Problem**:

- With a normal HPA like the code below, each Pod's environement variable `REPMGR_PARTNER_NODES` has a older value.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: "test-hpa"
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: StatefulSet
    name: "test-postgresql-ha-postgresql"
  minReplicas: 4
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      targetAverageUtilization: 40
```

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: Helm: Sadly, Nope! :(

I ended up using CrunchyData for Database instead https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator